# How do you remove the cell borders in Vaadin 8 Grid?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8, vaadin-grid

I would like to remove the border around all the cells in Vaadin 8's Grid. I don't believe it's possible to do with code, and the css for Table doesn't apply to Grid, therefore how do you do this for Grid?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 3):

Please try this. Im not sure if it has to be nested, but it should work this way.

```
.v-grid {
        .v-grid-cell {
            border: 0px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how you also remove the border on the outside of the grid?

Comment: Try `.v-grid-body` or `.v-grid-tablewrapper`